# What are the (Ten) commandments sent to the prophet Musa (pbuh)?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-musa, surat-al-araf

We know from verses like [this one](http://quran.com/7/150) that Musa (alayhi salaam), like the previous nations believe, did indeed receive tablets with some fiqh (rulings) from Allah (azza wa jal) when he visited Him in Tuwa. And that he broke the tablets.

Do we have any verses or ahadith that explicitly mention what was listed on those tablets? I can't recall ever reading this.

Comment: An answer to this question needs to be very comprehensive and review almost every Tafsir and many Hadith books. Also it can run to many pages.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know any authentic source (Quran or Sunnah) which explicitly gives in details the contents of the Tablets/Tauraat given to Musa (Peace be upon him).   Nor is there proof that the contents were the ten Commandments.  There is a Tafseer, that I follow, and am going to use to try answer your question.

All messengers had nine/ten commandments/Wasayah which was the base of the deen, and they gave to their people.  These nine/ten commandments are mentioned in Surat Al An'aam Ayah 151-153

and the ten Wasayah in those Ayat were the ones which were given to the previous peoples on the tongues of their messengers

> ذَٰلِكُمْ وَصَّاكُم بِهِ
>
> This He has commanded you

And so this is what Musa gave, and then after that the Tauraat came to explain it and expand on them, just like the Madani Suar came and expounded on that which came before in Makkah.

Sources: [تفسير المنار](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1143&idto=1144&bk_no=65&ID=372)

Answer (score 0):

Just look it up in the [Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0). It's not prohibited.